# Updating Android App - Maps Problems

Tags: android, google-api, android-maps

I need to update an Android app that was developed by someone else. Update by itself is simple, it's simple changes to XML layouts. 
So I have a following plan:

- update an app (done)
- test it on emulator (- maps don't work) stuck here!
- test it on devices
- release updated version to the store.

Unfortunately I am having mulitple problems with the app.
At first, it doesn't compile because the Project Build Target API was set to Android 2.3.3.
Is there any reason why it wasn't set to Google APIs 2.3.3 ? 
When I change it to Google APIs it compiles and runs but I my maps don't display correctly.
All I can see is gray rectangle and annotations on top of it. I am getting following error message associated with it.

```
05-11 20:45:42.554: W/System.err(598): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
05-11 20:45:42.559: W/System.err(598):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
```

As far as I understood from searching with Google and Stack Overflow that might be related to signing up the application. Currently app is using v1 of Google Maps.

Deleting debug.keystore and key set doesn't help.

I am not sure how to proceed with it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make maps display you need a signing key that is associated with the API key application was using. Android API v1 is now deprecated, so your options are limited:

- contact previous developer and ask them for `debug.keystore`, which is stored in `~/.android/` or `C:/Users/user.name/.android/` directory or
- use release signing key for testing (this might be cumbersome)

Depending on what application is that it might also be a good or bad idea to switch to API v2. New API still has some ugly impl bugs, but you won't notice them if maps usage is simple. The API or v2 is pretty good.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer!
What about releasing the app, what information I will need from other developer? 

As far as I understand if I sign it by myself, I won't be able to 
update the app...

Comment: @JanuszChudzynski You need at least original release keystore with two passwords.

Comment: MaciejGórski 
I contacted the developer and he sent me the release key,
I exported my app using the key but when I test it on my device map still doesn't work. 
Any idea why it's happening...? Do you want me to create a new question for it?

Comment: @JanuszChudzynski New question would be better. You will get more feedback that way.

Comment: Thanks. I posted it here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624108/updating-android-app-maps-problems-part-2